# Conditional Probability, weather related

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If it is raining, I take my car to work 90% of the time, I take my bike 9%, and I walk 1%. If it is not raining, I take my car 10%, bike 60%, and walk 30%. What is the probability it is raining if I drive my car? BiKe? Walk?

I'm pretty sure I need to use Baye's theorem, and assign the probability of a variable, but then I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need more input, for example the overall probability of rain.

If you are in the Sahara and come by car, it is more likely that today is one of your moderately rare driving-in-the-sun days than that it is one of the *very* rare rain days.
And if you are in Bergen, Norway, and you come walking, it is more likely that today is one of your daredevil walking-in-the-rain days than one of the almost unheard of sunny days.